# Is it normal for Sitecore to take a long time to merge contacts?

Tags: xdb

Sitecore Experience Platform 8.1 rev. 160519.

I have created a customized contact identification processor for the renderLayout pipeline.

```
        if (Tracker.IsActive
            && Tracker.Current.CurrentPage != null
            && Tracker.Current.Session.Contact.Identifiers.Identifier != SitecoreContext.User.Name)
        {
            Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(SitecoreContext.User.Name);
            //...
        }
```

It takes one minute or more to display the page when visiting by clearing the cache on the public site. Looking at the Sitecore log, it seems that it takes a while to get to "StandardSession.Identify - merged".

> 18208 00:20:04 DEBUG [Analytics]:
> Contact is taken from Shared session:
> 4d43d0b0-2eef-4014-80c5-8a88d8a054b0
>
> 18208 00:21:01 DEBUG
> StandardSession.Identify - merged:
> 4d43d0b0-2eef-4014-80c5-8a88d8a054b0

Is there anyone who met the same phenomenon?
Please tell me how to solve if there are people who have resolved.

Comment: In 8.2 they rewrote this. So I would say on 8.1 there was probably an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I am in trouble because I can not update it soon.

I want to deal with methods other than updating.
Processing aggregation interval adjustment, for example.

What is the Issue like?

Comment: This is not a general 8.1 issue. Aggregation intervals will not speed up your merging.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal to take a few milliseconds up to 1 second as contact merging is a complex operation but merge times like you have are definitely not normal.

**Ensure Identify() is not called too often**

I've had the same issue but it was due to Identify() being called on every request slowing merge operations down massively. It should only be called once when the actual identification occurs. Double-check your code.

**Check custom MergeContactProcessors**

If you have custom MergeContactProcessors check if they might slowing down your merge operations.

**Call Identify() on Login, not on Page-Load**

If possible call .Identify() while the login form submits instead of at rendering time. This will lead to better UX as users tolerate a few seconds wait when logging in.

**Check MongoDB performance and connection**

I've not seen these issues with contact merging on 8.1. (~2 Mio Contacts in MongoDB) Contact merging was around 500ms-1s on average. There might be a performance or configuration issue there. I would also suggest contacting Sitecore Support on this.